# Entity Framework - mapping columns to a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

We took over a older desktop product database application which was used to maintain a simple online shop. The products have some basic information like price, manufacturer, photos, title, description etc.  The product translations for title and description (and other language specific information) are maintained directly in the main products table.

Sofar the product database table looks like this:

```
AbProduct
    Id
    Price
    ManufacturerId
    ManufacturerNumber

    ...more columns...

    TitleDe
    DescriptionDe
    TitleFr
    DescriptionFr
    TitleIt
    DescriptionIt
```

And the model:

```cs
public class AbProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set }
    public string ManufacturerNumber { get; set; }

    /*... more properties ...*/

    public string TitleDe { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionDe { get; set; }
    public string TitleFr { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionFr { get; set; }
    public string TitleIt { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionIt { get; set; }
}
```

Sofar the mapping between the database and model was done manually. All the CRUD operations were done with pure ADO.Net

Now we are moving to a new online shop system and the customer wants to add translations for new languages. There are going to be more changes and new features in the near future but at the moment the focus is at the new online shop and how to synchronize the data.

So we thought that in the first stage, we would only redo the synchronization part, create a new model based on the old one, improve it and introduce **Entity Framework (6 or core)** aswell. The database would stay the same for now.

We have encountered problems with mapping the new model and are unable to map the translation columns correctly.

**How can we map (with Fluent API) the column based translations to object/table based translation?**

The new improved model:

```cs
public class AbProductNew
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set }
    public string ManufacturerNumber { get; set; }

    /*... more properties ...*/

    public ICollection<AbProductTranslation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class AbProductTranslation
{
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public AbProductNew Product { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    /*... other language specific properties ... */
}
```